# Maximo Spatial: Configure text at top left corner of map?

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1/Spatial 7.6.0.5, there is text displayed in the top-left corner of the map by default:

[image]

The text is a concatenation of WONUM and DESCRIPTION.

Is it possible to configure this text so that it shows additional information?

<sup>*Keyword: Maximo Spatial*</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying information about the current record on the map as a label

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSG2D3_7.6.1/com.ibm.spl.doc/maps/t_display_record_info_on_map.html

Answer (score 2):

I would query `maxmessages` for `value like '%{0}%-%{1}%'`. If the query finds data, look in `msggroup` and `msgkey` of the results for values that sound promising. (For support reasons, use the Maximo front-end, Database Configuration > Messages, to search for the group/key and change the value.) If you do not get results, there *might* be something down in your Maximo directory under `IBM\SMP\maximo\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient` possibly under a `pluss` directory.